# python: raise child_exception, OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, popen

I execute a command in python using `subprocess.popen()` function like the following:

```
omp_cmd = 'cat %s | omp -h %s -u %s -w %s -p %s -X -' %(temp_xml, self.host_IP, self.username, self.password, self.port)
xmlResult = Popen(omp_cmd, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
```

In the shell it runs fine without error, but in Python I get:

```
  File "/home/project/vrm/apps/audit/models.py", line 148, in sendOMP
    xmlResult = Popen(omp_cmd, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1228, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
  OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I searched the error but none of them solved my problem. Does anyone know what's the cause of this issue?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you're going to pass the command as a string to `Popen` and if the commands have pipes to other commands in there, you need to use the `shell=True` keyword.

I'm not particularly familiar with the `omp` command, but this smells an awful lot like a useless use of cat.  I would think that a better way to achieve this would be to:

```
import shlex
omp_cmd = 'omp -h %s -u %s -w %s -p %s -X %s' \
%(self.host_IP, self.username, self.password, self.port, temp_xml)
xmlResult = Popen(shlex.split(omp_cmd), stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
```

Or, if it's not a useless use of cat (You really do need to pipe the file in via stdin), you can do that with subprocess too:

```
import shlex
omp_cmd = 'omp -h %s -u %s -w %s -p %s -X -' \
%(self.host_IP, self.username, self.password)
with open(temp_xml) as stdin:
    xmlResult = Popen(shlex.split(omp_cmd), stdin=stdin, 
    stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
```

Comment: You are right!! One more question, if shell=False, should the args be a list, right? What's the difference between these two ways?

Comment: To answer your question, that command that I stores in the file is 9000 lines long, my OS will give me "arg list too long error" :)

Comment: @da_zhuang -- yes, with `shell=False`, the args are typically a list.  I used the `shlex.split` function which takes a string and splits it up into a list the same way a typical shell would.  with `shell=True`, you pass a string and that string is evaluated by a shell.  with `shell=False` you pass a string or a list.  If a string, it is evaluated as if it was the only command.  (`"ls -l"` would fail since there is no command `ls -l`, only `ls`).  If it's a list, each element is taken as a argument.   `["ls", "-l"]`

Comment: @da_zhuang -- I've edited with a version with preserves the original reading from stdin, but still removes the dependence on `cat` and hence the need to use `shell=True`.  The problem with `shell=True` is that it is vulnerable to shell injection if given untrusted input.  (say `self.host_IP` somehow was assigned the value `"; rm -rf ~;"`)

Answer (score 0):

This error has also occured for me too with tox scripts, turns out that a virtualenv is created with tox which has an asolute path with length about 96 characters but whenever it takes your absolute 'bin/pip' path to near about 123 chars, there is an invocation error, OSError2.

'ERROR: invocation failed (errno 2),
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory'

Python: Python 2.7.6
virtualenv:15.1.0
tox: 2.9.1
pip: 9.0.1
ubuntu 14.04
test ran with coverage: django(1.8-1.11) tests with py27, py35 each

Resolution:
I created my virtualenv(with abs path <=(96-100) chars) first where tox is installed, cloned my project to be used with this tox installation and virtualenv, tox creates it own virtualenvs now and it runs fine.

hope it helps.