# python subprocess.Popen error in linux

Tags: python, linux

I am now using Python to run a command-line executable program that was developed by myself:

```
import subprocess
cmd = '../../run_demo'
print cmd
subprocess.Popen(cmd)
```

This script runs very well in windows. However, it runs on linux, the following errors are given:

```
Traceback:
  File "script.py", line 6, in <module>
     subprocess.Popen(cmd)
  File "/user/lib/python2.5/subprocess.py", line 623, in _init_
     erread, errwrite)
  File "/user/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 1141, in _execute_child
     raise child_exception
  OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

As the executable command is printed in the script `print cmd`, if I copy the content of `cmd`, and then run in the command line, then the executable program can run.  Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Is `run_demo` a script file ?? in which case the command would be `cmd = '../.././run_demo'`

Comment: @DOOM you don't need the `./`

Comment: What's your working directory when you run this? Does `../../run_demo` work from the shell when you're in that working directory?

Comment: Take a look at [Popen with string as commands](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11566967/python-raise-child-exception-oserror-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: @DOOM Thanks for comments. run_demo is an executable program (written in c++ and compiled with g++)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, as the error says:

> OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

there's no file such as `'../../run_demo'` in the path you're giving. My bet is that you're trying to call a script relative to the script's path whereas, it's relative to the path you're running it from.

So first thing, print what you've got at `../..`:

```
import os
print os.listdir('../../')
```

there you'll see if there's a `run_demo` within.

Then, print the path of the current script:

```
pwd = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), os.path.pardir))
```

and now try to play with the relative path to get from `pwd` to the `run_demo` path, for example:

```
rundemo_exec = os.path.join(pwd,'..','..','run_demo')
```

and finally, once you've verified all that, you want to call properly `Popen`:

```
subprocess.Popen([rundemo_exec])
```

or

```
subprocess.Popen(rundemo_exec, shell=True)
```

depending on whether you want to embed it in a shell or not.

N.B.: however the script is indeed or not in the path you're giving, you say you're making a "portable" application between linux and windows, so definitely you need to use `os.path.join()`.