# How to pass a json object or string to a process

Tags: python, json

I've got a program which executes other python scripts depending on data it receives. 
The data it receives is in json format and can be helpful to those executed scripts.

This is why I want these scripts to receive the json somehow. I thought of doing it using the `subprocess` module using `Popen` but I don't think it'll work since I have to send an escaped string or a json object (after the json.loads() method).
I can also write the json to a file and read it but that seems like poor choice.

So how do I achieve this elegantly?

Comment: Check out [zmq for python](https://github.com/zeromq/pyzmq). It provides a simple interface for sending serialized data between any process architecture using just ports on your machine.

Comment: You can just send the serialized JSON though STDIN.

Comment: Using `Subprocess.Popen()`?

Comment: @Shookie Will the parent process have multiple sub-processes running simultaneously, or will there only ever be one sub-process at a time?

Comment: @cpburnz - Currently it'll be one.

Answer (score 4):

If there will only be one sub-process at a time, and the parent will wait for the child to finish, you can just use [`Popen.communicate()`](https://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate). Example:

```
# Create child with a pipe to STDIN.
child = subprocess.Popen(..., stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

# Send JSON to child's STDIN.
# - WARNING: This will block the parent from doing anything else until the
#   child process finishes
child.communicate(json_str)
```

Then, in the sub-process (if it is python), you can read it with:

```
# Read JSON from STDIN.
json_str = sys.stdin.read()
```

---

Or, if you'd like a more complicated use where the parent can write multiple times to multiple sub-processes, then in the parent process:

```
# Create child with a pipe to STDIN.
child = subprocess.Popen(..., stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

# Serialize and send JSON as a single line (the default is no indentation).
json.dump(data, child.stdin)
child.stdin.write('\n')

# If you will not write any more to the child.
child.stdin.close()
```

Then, in the child you would read each line when desired:

```
# Read a line, process it, and do it again.
for json_line in sys.stdin:
    data = json.loads(json_line)
    # Handle received data.
```

Comment: Won't it be problematic since the json is escaped and so it'll read up until the first new line?

Comment: @Shookie That depends. If you do a whole `.read()` (waits for STDIN to be closed), the JSON can have as many new-lines as you want. If you want the JSON to be on only one line, you'll have to make sure the JSON is serialized without indentation and in which case you want to use `.readline()`.

Comment: I've done as you've said but I seem to get `childe_exception` thrown from `subprocess`. Could it be since my command is in the form of `python A/script.py`?
Also, in the second example you gave, wouldn't it be `child.stdin` instead of `sys.stdin`?

Comment: @Shookie Can you put the whole exception in your question or look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11566967/369450) if that's what you're experiencing? Yes, it should be `child.stdin` not `sys.stdin`.